# Adding ifelse() into a Map function

Tags: r, if-statement

I've got a simple `Map` function that scrapes text files from a blog site. It's pretty easy to get a scraper that gets all of the text files and downloads them to my working directory. My goal: use an `ifelse()` or a plain `if` statement to only scrape a file based on a certain date.

Eg, if four files were posted on 1/31/19, and I pointed my `ifelse` at that date, the function would return those four files. Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

# URL set up
url <- "https://www.example-blog/posts.aspx"
page <- html_session(url, config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE))

# Picking elements
links <- page %>% 
  html_nodes("td") %>% 
  html_nodes("a") %>% 
  html_attr("href") 

# Getting date elements
dates <- page %>%
  html_nodes("node.dates") %>% 
  html_text()

dates <- parse_date_time(dates, "%m/%d/%Y", tz = "EST", 
                     locale = Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"))

# Function 
out <- Map(function(ln) {

fun1 <- html_session(URLencode(
  paste0("https://www.example-blog", ln)),
  config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE))

write <- writeBin(fun1$response$content)

ifelse(dates == '2019-01-31', write, "He's dead, Jim")

}, links)
```

I've tried various ways to get that if statement in there, and also moving the `writeBin` around. (Usually the `writeBin` would not be vectorized - I did it for easy viewing in my `ifelse`). Error:

```
Error in ans[test & ok] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test & ok] : 
   replacement has length zero
```

If I leave out the `if` code, everything works great, it just returns many text files, when I only want the ones from the specified date.

Comment: Yeah it's not a real site, I can't reproduce the site (work, unfortunately) - I'm still trying to find a good example as a replacement

Comment: The logic is not clear to me.  You already have a `dates` vector created outside.  then there are `links`.  Do you have the length of `links` equal to `'dates'` length.  In that case, 'dates' should be another argument to `Map` i.e. `Map(function(ln, y) if(y == "2019-01-31") do this else "He's dead, Jim", links, dates)`

Comment: You mean add that `if` statement within the `Map` function, and then also add in `dates` after the closing bracket, with `links`?

Comment: Assuming that you want to `write` when the 'dates' are of a particular value  or else return some string, (and assuming that 'dates' and 'links' have the same length, then 'links', 'dates' would be two arguments to `Map`, i.e. `Map(function(ln, y) ...., links, dates)`

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the description, it seems like check the corresponding 'dates' for each 'links' and then apply the `if/else`.  If that is the case, then we can have two arguments in `Map`

```
Map(function(ln, y) {
     fun1 <- html_session(URLencode(
           paste0("https://www.example-blog", ln)),
              config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE))

        write <- writeBin(fun1$response$content)

      if(y == '2019-01-31') {
        write 
      } else  "He's dead, Jim"
     },
         links, dates)
```